# SqlDataAdapter.Fill Is Using Wrong Field Type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldataadapter

For some reason, the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` method is treating one of the database fields as a `System.Decimal` even though it's defined in the database as `varchar(8)`.

```
string employeeSelectQuery = @"SELECT Employee_ID, Department, Email, Emp_Type,\
    First_Name, Job_Title, Last_Name, LogonID, Middle_Name, Display_Name, \
    SupervisorID FROM vw_tblEmployees;";
// ...
using( DataTable employeeTable = new DataTable() )
using( SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(employeeSelectQuery,
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMPLOYEE_DB"].ConnectionString) )
{
    sqlAdapter.Fill(employeeTable);
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("LogonID Data Type = {0}",
        employeeTable.Columns["LogonID"].DataType));
    // ...
}
```

This outputs

> LogonID Data Type = System.Decimal

Again, in the database, the `LogonID` field is a `varchar(8)`. Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: You might want to provide the actual SQL (`employeeSelectQuery`) that's getting executed.

Comment: I see that the SQL is querying a view. Can you also provide the view definition, so we can see what's happening there?

Comment: @TroyGizzi, No. Not at this time anyways as I only have select access. I can tell you it shouldn't be anymore than `SELECT LogonID, ... FROM tblEmployees WHERE Term_Date IS NULL OR Term_Date > GETDATE()` I can also tell you `SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'vw_tblEmployees' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'LogonID'` returns `varchar`

Comment: check your data in dataset by debugging it.If it will show decimal values n this then remove decimal places using function in sql query.

Comment: What are the `\ ` characters for that you show with your new lines? Are they there in your actual code or did you put them there for this website?

Answer (score 0):

For the life of me, I don't understand why this makes a difference but having a new line character in the `SELECT` statement seems to be what is causing this. If I remove the new line character, it detects the type correctly as `System.String`.

```
string employeeSelectQuery = @"SELECT Employee_ID, Department, Email, Emp_Type, First_Name, Job_Title, Last_Name, LogonID, Middle_Name, Display_Name, SupervisorID FROM vw_tblEmployees;";
```

Another option that seems to work is to setup the fields in the `DataTable` before calling `Fill()`.

```
employeeTable.Columns.Add("Employee_ID", typeof(string));
employeeTable.Columns.Add("LogonID", typeof(string));
// ...
sqlAdapter.Fill(employeeTable);
// ...
```

Comment: You could concatenate multiple strings to eliminate the scrolling.

Comment: @DStanley, True. I could also do `.Replace("\r\n","")`, but I'd really like to understand why this is. It's almost enough to make me stop using the black box that is `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: @DStanley, found another (better) solution as well.